# Cannot access classes in jar file that was imported by maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I want to use an external `jar` file. Since I use maven I've searched a bit and found a solution that looks like this:

`pom.xml:`

```
<repository>
    <id>ProjectRepo</id>
    <name>ProjectRepo</name>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

And on the FS I've placed the `jar` file under: `...\MyProject\lib\myGroupId\myArtifactId\myArtifactId-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

The `pom.xml` file looks fine ( no errors there ).
But the thing is I cannot access any class that is located inside this `jar` file.

I found [this](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/) tutorial and executed what's in there, but I still cannot use any class...

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the version number folder on your file system:

`..\MyProject\lib\myGroupId\myArtifactId\1.0.0\myArtifactId-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Note the `1.0.0` folder is the one that contains the jar file